# Access and explode comma-delimited data from multidimensional array then populate a new 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, delimited

I have a multidimensional array containing comma-separated strings like this

```
[
    [
        "users" =>  [
            'email' => 'test@yahoo.com ,testuser@yahoo.com',
            'username' => 'test,testuser',
            'description' => 'description1,description2'
        ]
    ]
]
```

I want to access the `users` subarray data, explode on delimiters, and create a new associative array of indexed arrays.

Desired result:

```
$User = array(
    'email' => array(
        'test@yahoo.com',
        'testuser@yahoo.com'
    ),
    'username' => array(
        'test',
        'testuser'
    ),
    'description' => array(
        'description1',
        'description2'
    )
);
```

Comment: have you tried anything? you might want to check php `explode`

Answer (score 7):

For only one index:

```
$arrayTwoD = array();
foreach ($valueMult[0]['User'] as $key => $value) { 
    $arrayTwoD[$key] = array_push(explode(',', $value));
}
```

If you have multiple indexes in `$multArray`:

```
$arrayTwoD = array();
foreach ($multArray as $keyMult => $valueMult) { 
    foreach ($valueMult['User'] as $key => $value) { 
        $arrayTwoD[$keyMult][$key] = array_push(explode(',', $value));
    }
}
```

or

```
$arrayTwoD = array();
foreach ($multArray as $array) { 
    foreach ($array['User'] as $key => $value) { 
        $arrayTwoD[$key] = array_push(explode(',', $value));
    }
}
```

Comment: this only works if the multi array has only one entry

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$array = array(...); // your array data
$formedArray = array();

foreach ( $array as $arr )
{
    foreach ( $arr['user'] as $key => $value )
    {
        $formedArray[$key] = array_push(explode(",",$value));
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($formedArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit repetitive, I know, but you can do like this as well:

```
foreach($array as $users) {
    foreach($users as &$value) { // &value is assigned by reference
        $users['users']["email"] = explode(",", $value['email']);
        $users['users']["username"] = explode(",", $value['username']);
        $users['users']["description"] = explode(",", $value['description']);
    }
}
```

But after that, you need to use `$value`. Refer to the official [PHP manual documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to know more about what the `&` symbol does here.

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/hfUgQ)

Comment: if you wouldn't override your results every time, you would run into a bad thing here... because you manipulate the foreach base array every time... this onley works because there is not much data AND because you override it all the time... if you would prevent it from overriding... this could end in a endless loop

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_map()` can be used to access the subset data (without declaring any new variables in the global scope) and make iterate calls of `preg_split()` to separate the delimited values into subarrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8F9BS))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($csv) => preg_split('/ ?,/', $csv),
        $array[0]['users']
    )
);
```